# What is the latest certification available for Xamarin?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm not quite comfortable in finding the correct certification available for Xamarin. Someone please guide me. If this is not the right channel to ask this, please redirect me to the correct channel.

Comment: Xamarin no longer offers any certification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no certification anymore for Xamarin. Microsoft Xamarin has removed the certification last year and Xamarin University Joins MS Learn.

> Please refer to the below links for more details.
>
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/next-evolution-xamarin-training-microsoft-learn/
> https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/microsoft-learn-free-xamarin-training/

---

> You could find all the materials for Xamarin for free in the below link.
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/browse/?term=xamarin

I hope that helps.

Comment: I have already completed all the courses here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/browse/?term=xamarin.. 
I couldn't find any certification for Xamarin.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no certifications available for Xamarin at present. It has been removed. Hope that helps. Kindly accept/upvote if the answer is helpful so that it will be useful for others as well.